# How to create and configure a utun device from the terminal?

Tags: ssh, vpn, tunnel

I want to create and configure a tun interface (utun device) using the command line that I can use with `ssh -w`. I tried `ssh -w 0` and got "Tunnel device open failed. Could not request tunnel forwarding." Any pointers for getting started? Is this possible on a Mac, or this is a Linux-only thing?